# active record - sort parent by by child attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Very new to active record.

Im trying to use active record to query 'changes' and order them by the closest start_time of their children (ctasks and legacy_ctasks).

If a change has ctasks and legacy_ctasks, use the earliest(minimum) start_time when sorting.

A change must have at least one ctask or legacy_ctask.

A change can have many ctasks and/or many legacy_ctasks

ctasks and legacy_ctasks both have a start_time field:

```
t.datetime "start_time":
```

Models:

```
class Change < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ctasks, -> { order "start_time ASC" }, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :legacy_ctasks, -> { order "start_time ASC" }, dependent: :destroy
end

class LegacyCtask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :change, touch: true
end

class Ctask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :change, touch: true
end
```

My current attempts are very sad:

```
Change.left_joins(:ctasks, :legacy_ctasks).order('ctasks.start_time ASC').order('legacy_ctasks.start_time ASC').distinct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering by the greatest value from either of two associated tables is a bit gnarly. Depending on how frequently you do this and your performance/space needs, you might consider caching the timestamp on the `changes` table so that you can easily index by it.

But I think you can take a couple approaches. One would be to join both tables and group by the changes.id. I think that should look something like this:

```rb
Change.select("changes.*")
  .group("changes.id")
  .left_joins(:ctasks, :legacy_ctasks)
  .order("GREATEST(MAX(ctasks.start_time),MAX(legacy_ctasks.start_time))")
```

Another option could be to use a lateral join to each table to pull the earliest record from each. This isn't as easy in AR but should be more performant and would be something like:

```rb
ctasks_joins_sql = <<-SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ctasks.start_time FROM ctasks WHERE ctasks.change_id = changes.id 
  ORDER BY start_time
  LIMIT 1
) as ctasks ON true
SQL
legacy_ctasks_join_sql = <<-SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT legacy_ctasks.start_time FROM legacy_ctasks WHERE legacy_ctasks.change_id = changes.id 
  ORDER BY start_time
  LIMIT 1
) as legacy_ctasks ON true
SQL

Change.select("changes.*")
  .joins(ctasks_joins_sql)
  .joins(legacy_ctasks_join_sql)
  .order("GREATEST(ctasks.start_time, legacy_ctasks.start_time)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I another soltion using callbacks came to me.  But I need to test it out.  
But I think I can add a calculated column to Change and use a callback to update it to the earliest ctask/legacy_ctask start_time